# Getting the values of data-* attribute and set a list of them

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-core, .net-core

I was trying to give a data-attribute to an element, them getting by id that element and try to access to data, but without success, Maybe its related to the way is displayed the HTML, I mean:

```html
<div class="col-md-2 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 ">
    <table>
        <thead>
            Servicios
            <tr>
                @foreach (var feature in hotel.Features.Take(6)) {
                <!-- DATA-* LISTA SERVICIOS-->
                <td class="col-md-6 showTruncateText" id="serviciosHotel" data-listServices="@feature.Code">
                    @feature.Description
                </td>

                <!--Esta pieza hace que se genere filas con 3 elementos. Una vez llega al
                    tercero, empieza otra fila.-->
                if (counter % 2 == 0) { @:
            </tr>
            <tr>
                } counter++; }
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
</div>
```

This is my html code and this is how its rendered:

```html
<div class="col-md-2 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 ">

    Servicios
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <!-- DATA-* LISTA SERVICIOS-->
                <td class="col-md-6 showTruncateText" id="serviciosHotel" data-listservices="APCO">
                    Aptos./Hab. con cocina
                </td>
                <!--Esta pieza hace que se genere filas con 3 elementos. Una vez llega al
                    tercero, empieza otra fila.-->
                <!-- DATA-* LISTA SERVICIOS-->
                <td class="col-md-6 showTruncateText" id="serviciosHotel" data-listservices="CAFE">
                    Cafetería
                </td>
                <!--Esta pieza hace que se genere filas con 3 elementos. Una vez llega al
                    tercero, empieza otra fila.-->
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <!-- DATA-* LISTA SERVICIOS-->
                <td class="col-md-6 showTruncateText" id="serviciosHotel" data-listservices="CFTE">
                    Caja fuerte individual
                </td>
                <!--Esta pieza hace que se genere filas con 3 elementos. Una vez llega al
                    tercero, empieza otra fila.-->
                <!-- DATA-* LISTA SERVICIOS-->
                <td class="col-md-6 showTruncateText" id="serviciosHotel" data-listservices="ITNS">
                    Punto de Internet
                </td>
                <!--Esta pieza hace que se genere filas con 3 elementos. Una vez llega al
                    tercero, empieza otra fila.-->
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <!-- DATA-* LISTA SERVICIOS-->
                <td class="col-md-6 showTruncateText" id="serviciosHotel" data-listservices="JARD">
                    Jardines /Terraza
                </td>
                <!--Esta pieza hace que se genere filas con 3 elementos. Una vez llega al
                    tercero, empieza otra fila.-->
                <!-- DATA-* LISTA SERVICIOS-->
                <td class="col-md-6 showTruncateText" id="serviciosHotel" data-listservices="JUEG">
                    Parque infantil
                </td>
                <!--Esta pieza hace que se genere filas con 3 elementos. Una vez llega al
                    tercero, empieza otra fila.-->
            </tr>
            <tr>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
</div>
```

So far here, everything ok, but in the js part is where I am getting the wrong answers, I mean I have tried a lot of ways but the most closer I get was `null` and `undefined`.

```js
    var dataServicios = document.querySelector('serviciosHotel').dataset;
    for (var i in dataServicios) {
        console.log(i, dataServicios[i])
    };
    var listaServicios = document.getElementById('serviciosHotel');
    var listaServicios2 = listaServicios.getAttribute('data-listservices');
    console.log(listaServicios2);

    var dataServicios2 = document.getElementById("serviciosHotel");
    var nombreServicio = dataServicios2.dataset.listServices;
    console.log(nombreServicio);

    var serviciosdelhotel = document.getElementById("serviciosHotel");
    var ratings = serviciosdelhotel.getAttribute("data-listServices");
    console.log(ratings);

    JQUERY
    var servicioshotelenrique = $("#serviciosHotel");

    var owner = servicioshotelenrique.data("listServices");
    console.log(owner);
    var dataServicios = $('#serviciosHotel').data();

    for (var i in dataServicios) {
        $('<li>', {
            text: i + ': ' + data[i]
        }).appendTo('#out');
    }
    console.log(dataset(document.getElementById('serviciosHotel')[0]));
    $("#serviciosHotel").click(function () {

        var id = $(this).attr('data-listServices');
        console.log(id);
    });
    console.log($("#serviciosHotel").data("listServices"));
```

What I am doing wrong?? its first time I work with data-attributes and isn´t supose to be difficult but...you know I cannot see clear.
Thank you very much!!

Comment: Repeating `id="serviciosHotel"` is wrong, it should be unique. `class` is the one who should be repeated

Comment: Yes thank you, what do you think of using `classname` or `name` to reference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Watch your capitals. Data attributes are case sensitive.

```
console.log($("#serviciosHotel").data("listServices"));
```

Should be

```
console.log($("#serviciosHotel").data("listservices"));
```

Then it works.

Comment: And how do you set them to a list to retrieve all of the data-attributes to a list??

Comment: don't use a parameter, just use $('#idElement').data()

Comment: Right again!, but it only shows 1 value and it should be like a lot of them, why??, It should get values from every one html element not this : `{listservices: "APCO"}
listservices: "APCO"` . It should be like 50!!!

Comment: That's because you're using ID's instead of classes :) Get all elements with a specific class then loop those to get each data-id

Comment: Thank you, Ill post another question related to this one!!

Answer (score 1):

According to me, you're writing way too much JS code to retrieve data that come from your back-end model (or maybe the `hotel` variable is an injected service?).

Considering the data are coming from your back-end model, a nice workaround would be to write the code below in your CSHTML file.

```
<script>
    var model = @Html.Raw(Json.Serialize(Model));
</script>
```

If your JS is in a separate file, you could store the data in a hidden HTML element.

You could also put your JS code in a JS class, and inject the data in the constructor parameters, like this:

```
<script>
    var view = new NameOfTheViewClass(@Html.Raw(Json.Serialize(Model)));
    view.init();
</script>
```

Comment: Hi  @bmartins , your answer sounds really nice and crazy, where I can found a good source for this thins in asp.net core?? . Also just want to use one the above methods, that js repeteated were trys I was trying to test.

Comment: @Html.Raw is supported in .net core as well, actually i guess that all HTML helpers are still supported (even if tag helpers are prefered instead of old-style HTML helpers).

Comment: Where Can I learn about HTML Helpers and tag helpers?? Just for ask a quality resource jeje, thank you!!

Comment: You can find official documentation about tag helpers on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/intro?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: You don't need to worry about HTML helpers since you are using .net core. Anyway, some are still useful, the one I used is documented here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.rendering.ihtmlhelper.raw?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: Thank you @bmartins!, I´m going to make use of this!(: